# What is the purpose of defining a macro that returns its parameter? E.g. #define U(x) x

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, lex

I have the following code in an old lexical analyzer generated by Lex:

```
#define U(x) x
#define input() (yysptr>yysbuf?U(*--yysptr):nextc<yylastc?*(Uchar*)nextc++:yytok())
```

where the variables in the `input()` macro are defined as follows:

```
#define linebufsize BUFSIZ+200
char linebuf0[linebufsize];
char *yylastc = linebuf0;
char *lastc = linebuf0, *nextc = linebuf0;
int yytok() { /*long function*/ };
```

What is the point of `#define U(x) x` other than, say making the code more "configure-able"?

Comment: Using a macro can causes additional or earlier replacement of tokens in it than otherwise. That is sometimes necessary when using the `#` or `##` operators. But I do not see a need for that in this case. I suspect you are on the right track with making the code configurable—the Lex user could replace the definition of `U(x)` with something else. From that context alone, I do not know what else would be desirable.

Comment: There is no good reason for that.